# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Projects'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

My MVC app is returning SqlExceptions when trying to access any table in my database.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Projects'.

My app uses LINQ for the data layer.

If I use an old DLL it works fine, (so doesn't seem to be a problem with the DB) just this latest app DLL that I've uploaded.

**details**

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Projects'.]
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection) +1950890
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846875
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj) +194    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
> runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj) +2392
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +83
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async) +954
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method) +32
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method) +141
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior) +12    System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
> System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query,
> QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
> parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
> lastResult) +975
> System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query,
> QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
> userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +113
> System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
> query) +344
> System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +35    System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +247    System.Linq.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext() +108    System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +259    System.Linq.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext() +108    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +7665172    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +61    Mezza_crm.Controllers.ProjectsController.GetProjectList(NameValueCollection form) in C:\mezza_crm\mezza_crm\Controllers\ProjectsController.cs:164
> Mezza_crm.Controllers.ProjectsController.List() in
> C:\mezza_crm\mezza_crm\Controllers\ProjectsController.cs:53
> lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +39
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
> controller, Object[] parameters) +17
> System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
> parameters) +24
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__7()
> +52    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
> filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +254   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__9() +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
> IDictionary`2 parameters) +192
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, String actionName) +399
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +126
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
> +27    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
> requestContext) +7
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
> +151    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +57
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
> httpContext) +7
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +181    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Answer (score 91):

Check the Initial Catalog parameter in your connection string.  It may be that your code is looking in the wrong database for the Projects object.

For example, if you have database syncing setup in such a way that only a subset of the master-database's tables are transferred, you can encounter this error if Linq to SQL is expecting all tables to be in the database pointed to by the connection string.

Comment: Connections string is fine. Web.Config has not changed since last release and last release worked fine.

Comment: Following the directions from Azure and copying the connections string from the Azure portal was wrong. The correct, or what I modeled after, was here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use. This sure helped get me pointed in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

I have seen that the new versions when you define the resulting entities better define them in the following way if you handle a different scheme, I had a similar problem

You must add System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


 [Table("InstitucionesMilitares", Schema = "configuracion")]
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you have access to the SQL Server you are querying?
Can you see a Table or View called dbo.Projects there?
If not, that would be a good place to look.

Linq to SQL creates an object map between the database and the application. If your new DLL that you're deploying doesn't match with the database anymore, then this is the sort of error you'd expect to get.

Do you perhaps have different database schemas between your development environment and the deployment environment?

Comment: Yep dbo.Projects exists and has not changed since last release. 

I have made a few changes to another table and added two tables. But I have mirror the changes in the DB on the server.

Usually I get something like this if I make a change in dev and forget to mirror the change on the server.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Actual'.

But once I fix the table it usually works.

Thanks for the speedy response.

Answer (score 7):

This maybe due to an incorrect table name from where you are fetching the data. Please verify the name of the table you mentioned in asmx file and the table created in database.

Answer (score 6):

Delete _MigrationHistory table in (yourdatabseName > Tables > System Tables) if you already have in your database and then run below command in package manager console

```
PM> update-database
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to do this way

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

or if you use .net core try it

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("Usuario");
}
```

Replace Usuario for your Entity Name, like a DbSet<<**EntityName**>> Entities without Plural

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR:** Check that you don't connect to the same table/view twice.

```
FooConfiguration.cs    
builder.ToTable("Profiles", "dbo");
...

BarConfiguration.cs
builder.ToTable("profiles", "dbo");
```

For me the issue was that I was trying to add an entity that **connected to the same table as some other entity that already existed**.

I added a new DbSet with entity and config, thinking we don't have it in our solution yet, however after searching for table name through all solution I found another place where we already connected to it.

**Switching to use existing DbSet and removing my newly added one** solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this problem could be a property setting of the database (Sql2008R2 with .NET4).

- Problem is reproducible at will when changing the COLLATION value of a database.

To display COLLLATION, use the Sql Server Mgmt Studio.

- Right-click the database and select Properties -> General, Then look under *Maintenance* for the COLLATION value

To change COLLATION, (still) use the Sql Server Mgmt Studio.

- Right-click the database and select Properties -> Options, From there, you can change the COLLATION value

Comment: What is one suppose to change it to?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in that phase of development where you have an method inside your context class that creates testdata for you, don't call it in your constructor, it will try to create those test records while you don't have tables yet. Just sharing my mistake...

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was because I had made a database in my LocalDb.
If that's the case then you have to write is as shown below:

```
    "SELECT * FROM <DatabaseName>.[dbo].[Projects]"
```

Replace  with your database name.
You can probably also drop the "[ ]"

Answer (score 0):

If you use two databases you can add another **DataClasses.dbml** and map the second database into it.
It works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The cause was that I had created a table with wrong schema(it ought to be `[dbo]`). I did the following steps:

1. I dropped all tables which does not have a prefix "dbo."
2. I created and run this query:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Cars(IDCar int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,Name varchar(25) NOT NULL,    
CarDescription text NULL)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried almost all the answers from below list, but did not work for me. But read the exception well and then tried **rename my Dbset name TransactionsModel to Transactions** 
 and it work for me.

old Code:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        //....
        public DbSet<Models.TransactionsModel> TransactionsModel { get; set; }
    }
```

New Code:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        //....
        public DbSet<Models.TransactionsModel> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
```